# How to prevent mobile devices to play video outside the browser?

Tags: html, video, html5-video, html5-canvas, mobile-webkit

I've embedded an mp4 file using the html5 tag. But when I play the video in the native of a mobile device, it opens the video in a separate video player, playing it fullscreen. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: See: stackoverflow.com/questions/9000624/html5-video-behavior-on-mobile-devices

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. 
Moreover, the resolution of such a video would be really small on an iphone for example, making it pretty useless.